# Rails: Undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently trying to make a tennis website using RoR. This website has a backend and currently has two tables in the database, users and events. I am trying to make a has_many relationship between the two tables and then make a form that lets the users sign up for these different events. I am pretty close but I keep running into this error in my view:

```
    undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

   <%= link_to event.title, event %>
  | <%= link_to "delete", event, method: :delete %>

   <%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(event_id: @user.id)) do |f| %>
   <div><%= f.hidden_field :event_id %></div>
     <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
   <% end %>
```

Here is my relationships controller

```
    class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController

      def create
       @relationship = Relationship.new(relationship_params)
       @user = User.find(params[:relationships][:event_id])
       current_user.follow!(@user)
       respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to @user }
       end
     end
    end
```

And the relevant part of my events controller:

```
   def new
     @event = Event.new
   end

   private

   def event_params
     params.require(:event).permit(:title, :Venue, :Time, :Date)
   end
```

Not sure how to fix this error, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check that your user is being populated. It looks like it isn't since it's saying it's nil.

Comment: I'm currently signed in as a user and there are 100 users in my users table.

Comment: That is good, but make sure it's actually being loaded. in your controller puts the params[:relationships][:event_id] to console. It might also be good to make sure the data you are passing in exists via rails console

Comment: `@user` in your view is `nil`. That's what you have to fix. In `new` you're only defining an `@event`, not a `@user`.

Also you're setting `event_id` to the id of a user. Are you sure that's correct? Seems strange to me.

Comment: In your view you're using event.title while in the controller when you need @event if it's the view for events/new.

Comment: Sorry I'm new RoR, no I guess I don't want to set event id to the user id. I want to assign the current user to the event that they clicked sign up for. I would need to include '@user = User.new' in my events controller?

Answer (score 4):

You should initialize the @user variable

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @event = Event.new
end
```

Comment: Now I'm getting NoMethodError in Events#index `<div class="hero-unit">
<% provide(:title, 'All Events') %>
<h1>All Events</h1>

<body>
<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="events">
    <%= render @events %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>

</body>

</div>`

Comment: im not sure how is your code structure, but I assume you should create def index in event controller and make index.html in view/event

Comment: I have both those things currently. My index is in views/events and in my events controller I have `def index
  @events = Event.paginate(page: params[:page])
 end`

Answer (score 1):

In your controller new action you have to define `@user`. Currently this variable is empty. So if you call the `id` method on something that's not existent you'll get the error `undefined method id for Nil...`

For example like this:

```
def new
  @user = User.find(1)
  @event = Event.new
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when working on a **Rails** application. The issue was that I was calling an unnecessary instance variable in my controller.

**Here's it**:

I was calling an unnecessary `@admin` instance variable in `log_in @admin`

**sessions/admins_controller.rb**

```
def create
  user = User::Admin.find_by(email: params[:sessions_admin][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:sessions_admin][:password])
    log_in @admin
    format.html { redirect_to users_admin_url(user), notice: 'Admin was successfully logged in.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: users_admin_url(user) }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @admin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

But error message was being flagged by rails in a corresponding helper file that I included in my `application_controller` file.:

**sessions/admins_helper.rb**

```
module Sessions::AdminsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
end
```

I simply had to modify the **method call** in the **create action** in `sessions/admins_controller.rb` from:

```
log_in @admin
```

to

```
log_in user
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**